What are the parts of a set operation result called?
Let's take some set operation, like union or intersection.
The term "set operation" refers to the action to be performed. Is there a name for the result, as an analogue for "sum" for addition, or "quotient" as one part of division. Or does one not exist and we use something like "set operation result"?
For the basic set operations, we commonly consider the elements that are exclusive to one operand, ones that are exclusive to the other operand, and ones that are shared by both operands. Is there a collective noun generalizing the "exclusive to first," "exclusive to second," and "shared by both" concepts? I've been calling them "domains" in my documentation, but I doubt that's the actual name. Worse, this may be confusing with any actual math term named "domains." Would I need to use a conventional term here too, like "parts of a set operation result"?
(I wanted to add a "nomenclature" tag, but my reputation isn't high enough.)

The result of a union operation is generally called the "union" of two (or more) sets, and the result of an intersection operation is called the "intersection" of two (or more) sets; is there a specific operation you have in mind that you're asking what the result is called?

"Inputs/Arguments/Operands" and "Outputs/Results/Returns"? Sometimes one writes the domain with a hyphen to emphasize membership. For example an "$R$-linear combination" or $\mathfrak{U}$-small. Very particular question, I feel like most people just choose something and roll with it...

@BrianTung, no particular operation; I'm looking for a term that could work for any possible set operation. But, as far as I know, there isn't a collective term for sums, differences, products, quotients, and remainders together either. That would suggest simply "set operation result," as an analogy to the "arithmetic operation result" just given.
